# Polymer 1.0: Wait for multiple iron-ajax requests to finish

Tags: ajax, promise, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have multiple iron-ajax tags on the page e.g.:

```
<iron-ajax
            auto
            id="ajaxCall1"
            url="/data/test1.json"
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="_myAjaxCall1ResponseHandler"
            last-response="{{_myAjaxCall1LastResponse}}"
            debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>

<iron-ajax
            auto
            id="ajaxCall2"
            url="/data/test2.json"
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="_myAjaxCall2ResponseHandler"
            last-response="{{_myAjaxCall2LastResponse}}"
            debounce-duration="300">
 </iron-ajax>
```

How can I wait for both requests to be completed before I do another action? I don't care about the order of requests, just they they are both completed.

Thanks.

Comment: one way will be to use flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observing multiple properties triggers the observer only when [both become defined](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#multi-property-observers). Thus, if you observe both responses bound to `last-response` it will fire only once both requests are finished.

```
Polymer({
  observers: [
    '_requestsFinished(_myAjaxCall1LastResponse, _myAjaxCall2LastResponse)'
  ],
  _requestsFinished: function(res1, res2) {
    // will only fire when res1 and res2 are non-undefined
  }
});
```

The trick is to unset the properties before requests are triggered again so that the observer waits for both to become defined again. See the snippet below.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  properties: {
    prop1: Object,
    prop2: Object,
    observer: {
      value: 'not fired'
    }
  },
  observers: [
    'observeBoth(prop1, prop2)'
  ],
  observeBoth: function(prop1, prop2) {
    console.log('observer');
    this.observer = 'fired';
  },
  set1: function() {
    console.log('prop1');
    this.prop1 = 'x';
  },
  set2: function() {
    console.log('prop2');
    this.prop2 = 'x';
  },
  unset: function() {
    this.prop1 = undefined;
    this.prop2 = undefined;
    this.observer = 'not fired';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      Observer: {{observer}}
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="set prop1" on-tap="set1" />
      <input type="button" value="set prop2" on-tap="set2" />
      <input type="button" value="unset props" on-tap="unset" />
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will this work for multiple instances of same call like ajaxCall1 made 5 times and ajaxCall2 made 3 times ?

Comment: I don't understand. You mean you want to trigger an observer only after multiple ajax calls?

Comment: yes like in your answer the observer will fire after 1 ajaxCall1 and 1 ajaxCall2 as both the responses will have value by then but consider a situation where ajaxCall1 is made 5 times and ajaxCall2 call is made 7 times and i want a callback after all the 12 calls are completed can i set such an callback ?

Comment: I think it's specific enough that you probably should take care of that yourself with some counters and a little logic.

Comment: counters are a bit hack kind of thing i looking for resolve all promises kind of thing which can be a more clean answer

Comment: Do you have to use `iron-ajax`? If not maybe consider `Promise.all()` and `fetch`?